# can a timesten replication agent hold deadlock to itself?

Tags: oracle, timesten

I am experiencing a strange issue, where the timesten subdaemon core dumped, and in analysing the tterrors log, I find a stream of lock errors, where the replication agent is trying to obtain a lock held by itself(see the pids in below log message), what could cause this ? I can see the logs is at least repeated for the next 7 minutes and ultimately lead to the core dump, has this been a problem with timesten/oracle ? i cannot find any known bugs , and i am not able to reproduce the problem as well

under what circumstances ,can a replication agent lock it self out ? and wouldnt release its lock in this case

15:59:23.89 Warn: REP: 14037: COLLECTORDB:receiver.c(9880): TT6003: TT6003: Lock request denied because of time-out Details: Tran 28.27845 (pid 14037) wants X lock on rowid BMUFVUAAAAAACHfK+g, table DBUSER.CUSTOMERS. But tran 7.327400504 (pid 14037) has it in X (request was X). Holder SQL () -- file "tindex.c", lineno 4429, procedure "sbTixNext()"